# How to link web app to a Firebase Hosting site using CLI

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

Is it possible to link the web app in my Firebase project to a Firebase Hosting site using CLI instead of the following console dialog?

[image]

Comment: If it turns out that this isn't possible, you can always file a feature request with Firebase support. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Thanks. The necessity of requesting this feature depends on the benefits of this linking: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64409754/3082178.